# Check if node is displayed as page?

Tags: 7, rules, database

In Drupal 6 to check if node is displayed as page we can use:

**Select the condition to add** - > `Check a truth value`

**Truth value** - > `<?php echo $page ?>`

How to do this in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) 2.x for Drupal 7? I don't see the condition with name `Check a truth value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I have interpreted what you're trying to do, try adding the Event "Content is viewed", with the Condition "Content is of type" and configure the Condition to be of node type: 'Page'. If you could explain exactly what you're trying to achieve I may be able to suggest a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way

EVENT: Content is viewed of type [...]

Conditions: **Execute custom PHP code: "return $view_mode == 'full';"** (without the quotes)

Actions: Unflag, flag and so on...